# How to use outside packages inside R dbplyr mutate

Tags: r, dbplyr

I am currently pulling in a data set with dbplyr using the following:

```
connectInfo <- dbConnect(
  odbc(),
  Driver = "SQL Server",
  Server = "myServerName",
  Database = "myDatabaseName",
  Trusted_Connection = "True"
)

tbl(connectInfo, "tableName") %>%
  summarise(
    nbDate = LEFT(nbDate, 5),
    book,
    rateFeeChg
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    rateFeeChg = rateFeeChg * 100
  )
```

With the following output:

```
   nbDate    book rateFeeChg
    <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>
 1  38348 Classic  0.0000000
 2  38744 Classic  2.1270990
 3  39640 Classic  2.8999999
 4  40423 Classic  0.0000000
# ... with more rows
```

What I want to do is convert these 5 digit date values into regular looking date values inside the mutate function. 
I know by using the janitor library I can easily convert it, but when when I try putting

```
mutate(
    rateFeeChg = rateFeeChg * 100,
    nbDate = janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(nbDate)
)
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error in janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(nbDate) : 
  object 'nbDate' not found
```

Comment: You have to understand that each function that you use inside a mutate call in a `dbplyr` chain either has an adhoc translation to SQL, or is tried as an SQL function, so you can't use the code from another package there, unless you use `collect` first of course.

Comment: I think `as.Date` is translated, so you may be able to use it, but I believe excel dates have a different zero than R dates so you may have to add or substract a constant. before transforming.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper thank you for the fast response. When I attempt to use as.Date I was receiving the error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. So if I have to stick with collect then will I just transform the output into a dataframe (for example) and then use my function on the column as normal?

Comment: try converting to numeric first, I hadn't seen your column was character. `as.Date(as.numeric(nbDate)+whatever_constant_is_needed)`

Comment: Take also a look at the accepted answer here, it might be used to format dates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438567/how-to-use-extract-through-dbplyr-when-connecting-to-an-oracle-db/49459907#49459907

Answer (score 2):

the main thing is that in MS SQL this conversion will first need to be into `datetime`, and then into `date`. Since in `dbplyr` there are currently no function that coerces into `datetime`, the best thing is to use `sql()` to pass the MS SQL command.  This way, you can keep all of your process server side, and avoid `collect()`ing data into R memory.  The default `datetime` conversion in SQL seems to have the same base date as Excel, so you should get the same dates back.  Here's a proposed solution I just tested on my system:

```
tbl(connectInfo, "tableName") %>%
   summarise(
   nbDate = sql("CAST(LEFT(nbDate, 5) as datetime)"),
   book,
   rateFeeChg
 ) %>%
 mutate(
  nbDate = as.Date(nbDate),
  rateFeeChg = rateFeeChg * 100
 )
```